# Problem calling a C++ program from C#

Tags: c#

I have a C++ program (Test.exe) that takes in a number *N* (passed as command line argument) and generates coordinates for *N* rectangles written to a text file.

I have tested this via the command line and in Visual Studio, and on both occasions the file is written with the expected output.

In a C# program I enter *N* in a textbox, click a button and my event code is as follows:

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = "Test.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = num;
p.Start();
// read the file that Test.exe created
```

A file is not written by Test.exe.

Any suggestions as to why Test.exe doesn't write the file when it is called from the C# program?

**Problem Found** 
The file was being written in the directory where the C# program was executed from NOT from where the C++ program was located.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you forgot `p.WaitForExit()` right after the `p.Start()` line.

Comment: StartInfo.WorkingDirectory would be an excellent candidate as well.  The default is rarely writable.

Comment: Even with using p.WaitForExit(), the file is not written

Answer (score 2):

Two points:

1. Make sure the working directory of `Test.exe` (`StartInfo.WorkingDirectory`) is set to a directory where the process has write access, and
2. If `Test.exe` needs process elevation, use `StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true` and `StartInfo.Verb = "runas"` to start an elevated process. Your C# program needs to be an elevated process to do this, you can use an application manifest file for this.